# React-native setState in a forEachLoop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a form validation in a react-native application, the process of my approach goes like the following:

1. When clicking the nextStep button, All fields errors and values
   states are grouped in two arrays.
2. Then I perform a forEach loop on the values array to check for null values.
3. If a null value is encountered, I map the value to the key in the errors state and change the error state to true.

My problem is that performing a setState in a loop will update only the last element in the array even with the ... spread operator.

this.state:

```
this.state = {
  step: 0,
  fields: {
    name: "",
    salonName: "",
    gender: "",
    email: "",
    description: "",
    openingHour: "",
    closingHour: "",
    workingDays: "",
  },
  stepOneErrors: {
    name: {
      status: false,
      text: "Name is required",
    },
    salonName: {
      status: false,
      text: "Salon name is required",
    },
    gender: {
      status: false,
      text: "Gender is required",
    },
    email: {
      status: false,
      text: "E-mail is required",
    },
  },
};
```

here is my formValidation function:

```
  validateForm = () => {
    const { name, salonName, gender, email } = this.state.fields;
    const keys = Object.keys(this.state.fields);
    const fieldsArray = [name, salonName, gender, email];
    fieldsArray.forEach((e, index) => {
      const input = keys[index];

      if (e === "") {
        this.setState({
          stepOneErrors: {
            ...this.state.stepOneErrors,
            [input]: {
              ...this.state.stepOneErrors[input],
              status: true,
            },
          },
        });
      }
    });
    return name === "" || salonName === "" || gender === "" || email === "";
  };
```

The execution works like the following:

- if I leave all the fields empty, then only the e-mail fields (last
  one) get the error message.
- if I fill the email field, only the gender field (right before the email field) get the error message.

etc.
Any help please with properly updating the state in a for loop?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
 this.setState((prevState) => ({
      stepOneErrors: {
        ...prevState.stepOneErrors,
        [input]: {
          ...prevState.stepOneErrors[input],
          status: true,
        },
      },
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

do the manipulation on a shallow copy of the state, and call `setState` only once after the loop

```
let stepOneErrors = [ ...this.state.stepOneErrors ]//shallow copy state
fieldsArray.forEach((e, index) => {
      const input = keys[index];
      if (e === "") {
          stepOneErrors= {
            ...stepOneErrors,
            [input]: {
              ...stepOneErrors[input],
              status: true,
            },
          }
        }
      }
this.setState({ stepOneErrors })
```

Comment: @Dennis Vash answered the question but then deleted his own answer which turned out to solve my problem.